# Export / import conda environment and package including local files

Tags: linux, package, conda

I want to make my analysis reproducible and want to use conda to make sure, specific software of a specific version is used. To do so, I set up an environment including some programs built from local source and scripts exporting some environment variables.

I exported the environment and built a package from the local files (basically following a procedure described here, post #2: [>link<](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/conda/cHBYGHgvMMI)):

```
conda env export > myenv.yml
conda package --pkg-name myenv --pkg-version 0.1 --pkg-build 1
```

On a different machine, I imported the environment without problems using

```
conda env create -f myenv.yml
source activate myenv
```

However, I got some trouble when trying to install the package:

```
conda install myenv-0.1-1.tar.bz2
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package '<unknown>::myenv-0.1-1'.
FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
Attempting to roll back.
FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
```

So I read a bit about channels and tried setting up a local channel with the package:

```
mkdir -p own_pkg/linux-64
mkdir -p own_pkg/noarch
mv myenv-0.1-1.tar.bz2 own_pkg/linux-64/
conda index own_pkg/linux-64 own_pkg/noarch
updating: myenv-0.1-1.tar.bz2
```

I added the following to `~/.condarc`

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - file://my/path/to/own_pkg
```

And then tried again to install but still:

```
conda install myenv
Fetching package metadata .............

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - myenv

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - file://my/path/to/own_pkg/linux-64
  - file://my/path/to/own_pkg/noarch
```

Even so in `/my/path/to/own_pkg/linux-64` the files `.index.json`, `repodata.json` etc. exist and the package is named and the tar.bz2 file referenced therein.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and/or what the appropriate workflow is to achieve my goal?

Thanks!

---

More information:

Source machine:

- Linux Ubuntu 16.04
- conda version 4.4.7
- conda-build version 3.2.1

Target machine:

- Scientific Linux 7.4
- conda version 4.3.29
- conda-build version 3.0.27